# Android Fragment java.lang.IllegalStateException: No host

Tags: java, android, fragment, fragmentmanager

I do a lot of search about this problem but no answer helps me.
I saw a same question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210617/fragmentmanager-illegalstateexception-no-host) but it can not help, so I post my question with the hope that any guy can help me. It's serious to me.
I have an `Activity`(called `activity` A, it's MainActivity) with `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`, which contains 5 `Fragments`.

In normal case, everything is ok. But some time if I try to re-open `A1`  with below scenario

1. Start `Activity` A
2. From one of 5 `fragments` above, I start a new Activity called B.
3. From B, I tried to start `Activity` C
4. From C, start `Activity` A above and clear all of the `activities` in backstack by 
   `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`

I got below `Error` :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No host
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1239)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1234)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2046)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1989)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1092)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)

Since now, I can not launch my app any more, each time I try to launch my application, I got the exception with the same Error in above.

I tried to use the solution in this [topic](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42601) but still can not resolve my issue

I do investigate and found that Exception occurs in FragmentManager class by code :

```
if (mHost == null && newState != Fragment.INITIALIZING) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No host");
    }
```

I have no idea why `mHost` is null and every time I try to call `commit` from `fragmentManager`, the `exception` will be thrown.

If I clear `data` of `application`, it will back to normal.

Comment: Can you post code for a simple example to help other people replicate?

Comment: It's a big project with many Activities and Fragments, and I in the log it did not point me which part causes the problem, So I don't know which one I could post in here :(

Comment: But that makes it very difficult for anyone to provide help.  Suppose you made a copy of your project and started stripping out irrelevant parts.  Ideally, you'll either identify the problem yourself (when you remove something and the problem goes away) or wind up with a simple example of how to reproduce the problem.