# FragmentManager IllegalStateException: No host

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**UPDATE**:
Crashes gone when i put nullcheks (fragment != null, getActivity() != null) whereever i could.

My app is using **ViewPager** (offscreen limit 5) with **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** initialized with **getSupportFragmentManager()**. Each page has it's own fragments and backstack.

App crashes on startup. Problem occurs only on **preLollipop** devices and emulator. Using latest support lbrary (tried 24.0.0 also - same result)
Stacktrace:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No host at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1273)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2138)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1254)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2062)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1051)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1632)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:637)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1237)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1085)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1611)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                              at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
>                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                              at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
>                                                                              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                              at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
>                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
>                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
>                                                                              at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
>                                                                              at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

Comment: can you show us some codes?

Comment: @AbdulAhad there's so much code regarding transactions and Fragments in total - so i have no idea what code to post (and it's not clear from the stacktrace from where problem is).

Comment: you can take a look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210617/fragmentmanager-illegalstateexception-no-host

Comment: before calling `setCurrentItem(()` check if `getActivity()` is null

Comment: Where do you call `setCurrentItem`? Can u add this code block?

Comment: I have the similar problem. But, I'm using ViewAnimator. The crash happens during rotation. It doesn't happen when I use SDK 24 + support library 24.2.1. The crash happens after I use SDK 25 + support library 25.0.0

Answer (score 1):

If you have nested Fragment (extends FragmentActivity), then use  getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager().

may be it will help you ..

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am using viewpager inside fragment and was using `getChildFragmentManager()` while setting viewpager adapter. It is also recommended to use this I guess.

There is also an issue, `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No host` exception was not showing everytime but it was showing too often when I called a method of viewpager containing Activity or coming back from another Activity class before setting `viewpager.setCurrentItem(POSITION);`

I tried in many ways and finally I changed `getChildFragmentManager()` to `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();`

After changing this `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No host` exception is not showing any more.

I think its related to Activity state issue which contains viewpager.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using viewPager ,  make sure you are following these practices

1. call super(fragmentManager) in your constructor
2. if you are using Viewpager inside a Fragment,  pass getChildFragmentManager in to Adapter